# how to delete row from sqlite database in iPhone from tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i want some help for deleting rows in database through Tableview.
In my app i am using SKDatabase file for query. now when i call delete query it doesn't work.
below is my code

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    i = indexPath.row;     
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [objappdel.sk deleteWhere:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID = %d",indexPath.row] forTable:@"Highlights_Table"];

        tablstr = [arrayFinal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@" %@",tablstr);
        [arrayFinal removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    [table1 reloadData];
}
```

if i am using delete all data query then it is working, i dont know tht how to solve this. please help.

Delete method code in SKDatabase.m

```
- (void)deleteWhere:(NSString *)where forTable:(NSString *)table 
{
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM %@ WHERE %@",
                 table,where];
    NSLog(@" %@",sql);
    [self runDynamicSQL:sql forTable:table];
}

- (BOOL)runDynamicSQL:(NSString *)sql forTable:(NSString *)table
{
   int result;
   NSAssert1(self.dynamic == 1,[NSString stringWithString:@"Tried to use a dynamic function on a static database"],NULL);
   sqlite3_stmt *statement;
   if (statement = [self prepare:sql]) 
   {
       result = sqlite3_step(statement);
   }        
   sqlite3_finalize(statement);
   if (result) 
   {
       if (self.delegate != NULL && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(databaseTableWasUpdated:)]) 
       {
           [delegate databaseTableWasUpdated:table];
       }    
       return YES;
       NSLog(@"Done");
    } 
    else 
    {
        return NO;
    }

 }


- (sqlite3_stmt *)prepare:(NSString *)sql 
{

    const char *utfsql = [sql UTF8String];
    NSLog(@" %s",utfsql);

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare([self dbh],utfsql,-1,&statement,NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        return statement;
    } 
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your table the field with name "ID" is exist ?? i mean confirm the field name. It should be "ID".

Comment: Yes field with Name "ID" is there.

Comment: You told that if you use delete all data query then it works. can you show me how you write that code ?? just a line of query.

Comment: [objappdel.sk deleteAllRowsForTable:@"Highlights_Table"] this is for delete all data

Comment: if you get this "DELETE FROM Highlights_Table WHERE ID = 2" in NSLog then try this query direct into your databse and check. If it is works there then there is no problem in your database side.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the objects from `SQLite` are **`NSNumber`** so instead of **`"ID = %d"`** you should replace with 
**`"ID == %@",[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];`**

I never used SKDatabase but I'm pretty sure the **"ID = %d"** won't generate a rule, you only have 1 `"="`, if the **`"ID == %@"`** isn't working you should try using **`"ID==%d"`**.

Comment: How is the delete function created? Can you show the implementation of this: **[objappdel.sk deleteWhere:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID = %d",indexPath.row] forTable:@"Highlights_Table"];** ?

Comment: None of them is working. i give NSLog at SKDatabase method, nd i can get this line "DELETE FROM Highlights_Table WHERE ID = 2"

Comment: in SKDatabase.m  - (void)deleteWhere:(NSString *)where forTable:(NSString *)table {

 NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM %@ WHERE %@",
      table,where];
    
      NSLog(@" %@",sql);
 [self runDynamicSQL:sql forTable:table];
}

Comment: - (BOOL)runDynamicSQL:(NSString *)sql forTable:(NSString *)table {
 int result;
 NSAssert1(self.dynamic == 1,[NSString stringWithString:@"Tried to use a dynamic function on a static database"],NULL);
 sqlite3_stmt *statement;
 if (statement = [self prepare:sql]) {
  result = sqlite3_step(statement);
    }  
 sqlite3_finalize(statement);
 if (result) 
 {
  if (self.delegate != NULL && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(databaseTableWasUpdated:)]) 
  {
   [delegate databaseTableWasUpdated:table];
  } 
  return YES;
        NSLog(@"Done");
 } else {
  return NO;
 }
 
}

Comment: - (sqlite3_stmt *)prepare:(NSString *)sql {
 
 const char *utfsql = [sql UTF8String];
    NSLog(@" %s",utfsql);
 
 sqlite3_stmt *statement;
 
 if (sqlite3_prepare([self dbh],utfsql,-1,&statement,NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        
  return statement;
 } else {
  return 0;
 }
}

Comment: First it will call "- (void)deleteWhere:(NSString *)where forTable:(NSString *)table " method, then it will go in "- (BOOL)runDynamicSQL:(NSString *)sql forTable:(NSString *)table" method,nd last in" - (sqlite3_stmt *)prepare:(NSString *)sql" method.

Comment: As far as I can see the problem isn't the function.If you try to delete without any arguments it works as i understood from you so maybe the ID is the problem , check and see if it works with another field.

Comment: [objappdel.sk deleteWhere:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label = %@ ",[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] forTable:@"Highlights_Table"]; i tried for my 2nd filed "Label" thn it gives EXC_Bad_ACCESS at this line.

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you put the deleteWhere: method in your post, it's hard work looking at all these comments

Comment: You should check the arrData to see if it's indeed allocated.

Comment: Thank you so much for help, problem is solved with below code line. IDstr = [[arrayFinal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"ID"];
        
        NSLog(@" %@",IDstr);

        [objappdel.sk deleteWhere:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID = ' %@ '",IDstr] forTable:@"Highlights_Table"];

Comment: So basically you were trying to delete an non-existing item from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try by putting quotes:

```
[objappdel.sk deleteWhere:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID = \"%d\"",indexPath.row] forTable:@"Highlights_Table"];
```

instead of:

```
[objappdel.sk deleteWhere:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID = %d",indexPath.row] forTable:@"Highlights_Table"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Highlights_Table *tableObj = [arrayFinal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[[DataManager mangedObjectContext] deleteObject:tableObj];

[[DataManager mangedObjectContext] save:&error];

[arrayFinal removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Highlight_Table is name of table in database. its not any file, so this code will not work.